# Can't bind properties to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

**RootObject.cs**

```
public class RootObject 
{
    private const string api = "";
    private const string mode = "json";
    private const string url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";

    public Coord coord { get; set; }

    public void Get(string city)
    {
        JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(new WebClient().DownloadString(url + city + "&appid=" + api + "&mode=" + mode));

        coord = new Coord(jsonData.SelectToken("coord"));

    }
}
```

**Coord.cs**

```
public class Coord
{
    private double lon;
    public double Lon
    {
        get { return lon; }
        set { lon = value;}
    }

    private double lat;
    public double Lat
    {
        get { return lat; }
        set { lat = value;}
    }

    public Coord(JToken coorddata)
    {
        this.Lon = Convert.ToDouble(coorddata.SelectToken("lon"));
        this.Lat = Convert.ToDouble(coorddata.SelectToken("lat"));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyMethod, CanExecuteMyMethod);
    }

    private string city;
    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteMyMethod(object parameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (City != "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteMyMethod(object parameter)
    {
        RootObject a = new RootObject();
        a.Get(City);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
  <vm:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel"></vm:ViewModel>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid >
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}}">
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="30" Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <Button Width="100" Height="30" Command="{Binding MyCommand }">pussh</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={???}}">
            <Label></Label>
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Text="{Binding Path=Lon}"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="50" Text="{Binding Path=Lat}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm newbie in MVVM stuff.
I tried to bind properties `Lat` and `Lon` to textbox in XAML (the `Lat` and `Lon` will be shown after button click), already tested with `DataContext` and `ObjectDataProvider`, but it didn't work. I guess I forget about something, but have no idea what it should to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), it's an interface your ViewModels and Models needs to implement if you want your `Binding` to be updated when the ViewModel/Model properties changes. Once you have a basic understanding of how `INotifyPropertyChanged` work, then you'll have to decide if you add `Lat` and `Lon` properties directly to your ViewModel or if you make a second ViewModel for your `RootObject` and bind to it.

Also, a good practice is to set the DataContext to the root element of the page (ie: Window), the DataContext is inherited by children if not specified.

Unfortunately, without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you won't be able to make your `Binding` show any updated value to `Lat` and `Lon`.

Note that your RootObject `a` is being destroyed at the end of `ExecuteMyMethod` at the moment, you'll probably want to change your logic here to keep a reference to the `a.Coord` value somehow.